# what is a browser variable in python?

Tags: python, variables, selenium, nameerror

I'm a newb trying to write a Selenium script using Python. There's a section of the script where I'm asking the program to wait until the iframe has appeared before selecting another element.

I've got and error:

NameError: global name 'browser' is not defined

I understand the nature of the problem - the variable needs to be defined before it can be used, but I don't know what to initialise the variable with!

I know this sounds like a strange question, as why would I use a variable that I haven't initialised. Problem is, that part of my code I took from a fix on here where the definition of the variable isn't given.

Any help much appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import unittest, time, re

class Gymboxtest3(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.base_url = "http://gymbox.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_gymboxtest3(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/Login")
        time.sleep(30)

        frame = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("iframe"))
        browser.switch_to_frame(frame)
```

Comment: Try using `self.driver` (or just `driver`) instead of `browser`.

Answer (score 1):

the error is at:

```
def test_gymboxtest3(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/Login")
    time.sleep(30)

    frame = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("iframe"))
    browser.switch_to_frame(frame) # <-- here
```

maybe you've meant `driver.switch_to_frame(frame)`? you're using `browser` yourself, but you never defined it beforehand.

Comment: Why did you copy the broken source code into your answer? :-/

Comment: just trying to be helpful.

Comment: People will look at your code and wonder why it doesn't work. It is more useful when you fix the errors :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `browser` with `driver`:

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)...
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
```